# Is it possible to set two fields as indexes on an entity in ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am new to ndb and gae and have a problem coming up with a good solution setting indexes.
Let say we have a user model like this:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()    
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)    
    fb_id = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Upon login if I was going to check against the email address with a query, I believe this would be quite slow and inefficient. Possibly it has to do a full table scan.

```
q = User.query(User.email == EMAIL)
user = q.fetch(1)
```

I believe it would be much faster, if User models were saved with the email as their key.

```
user = user(id=EMAIL)
user.put()
```

That way I could retrieve them like this a lot faster (so I believe)

```
key = ndb.Key('User', EMAIL) 
user = key.get()
```

So far if I am wrong please correct me.  But after implementing this I realized there is a chance that facebook users would change their email address, that way upon a new oauth2.0 connection their new email can't be recognized in the system and they will be created as a new user.  Hence maybe I should use a different approach:

- Using the social-media-provider-id (unique for all provider users)

and

- provider-name (in rare case that two twitter and facebook users share
  the same provider-id)

However in order to achieve this, I needed to set two indexes, which I believe is not [possible](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass).

So what could I do? Shall I concatenate both fields as a single key and index on that?

e.g. the new idea would be:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()    
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)    
    provider_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    provider_type = ndb.StringProperty()
```

saving:

```
provider_id = 1234
provider_type = fb
user = user(id=provider_id + provider_type)
user.put()
```

retrieval:

```
provider_id = 1234
provider_type = fb
key = ndb.Key('User', provider_id + provider_type) 
user = key.get()
```

This way we don't care any more if the user changes the email address on his social media.
Is this idea sound?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

Tim's solution sounded so far the cleanest and likely also the fastest to me. But I came across a problem.

```
class AuthProvider(polymodel.PolyModel):
    user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    active = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)  
    date_created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def user(self):
        return self.user_key.get()

class FacebookLogin(AuthProvider):
    pass
```

**View.py: Within facebook_callback method**

```
provider = ndb.Key('FacebookLogin', fb_id).get() 

# Problem is right here. provider is always None. Only if I used the PolyModel like this:
# ndb.Key('AuthProvider', fb_id).get()
#But this defeats the whole purpose of having different sub classes as different providers. 
#Maybe I am using the key handeling wrong?


if provider:
    user = provider.user
else:
    provider = FacebookLogin(id=fb_id)          
if not user:
        user = User()
        user_key = user.put()
        provider.user_key = user_key
        provider.put() 
return user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One slight variation on your approach which could allow a more flexible model will be to create a separate entity for the provider_id, provider_type, as the key or any other auth scheme you come up with

This entity then holds a reference (key) of the actual user details.

You can then

1. do a direct get() for the auth details, then get() the actual user details.
2. The auth details can be changed without actually rewriting/rekeying the user details
3. You can support multiple auth schemes for a single user.

I use this approach for an application that has > 2000 users, most use a custom auth scheme (app specific userid/passwd) or google account.

e.g

```
class AuthLogin(ndb.Polymodel):
     user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
     status = ndb.StringProperty()  # maybe you need to disable a particular login with out deleting it.
     date_created = ndb.DatetimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

     @property
     def user(self):
         return self.user_key.get()


class FacebookLogin(AuthLogin):
    # some additional facebook properties

class TwitterLogin(AuthLogin):
    # Some additional twitter specific properties
```

etc...

By using PolyModel as the base class you can do a `AuthLogin.query().filter(AuthLogin.user_key == user.key)`  and get all auth types defined for that user as they all share the same base class AuthLogin.  You need this otherwise you would have to query in turn for each supported auth type, as you can not do a kindless query without an ancestor, and in this case we can't use the `User` as the ancestor becuase then we couldn't do a simple get() to from the login id.

However some things to note, all subclasses of AuthLogin will share the same kind in the key "AuthLogin"  so you still need to concatenate the auth_provider and auth_type for the keys id so that you can ensure you have unique keys.  E.g.

```
dev~fish-and-lily> from google.appengine.ext.ndb.polymodel import PolyModel
dev~fish-and-lily> class X(PolyModel):
...    pass
... 
dev~fish-and-lily> class Y(X):
...    pass
... 
dev~fish-and-lily> class Z(X):
...    pass
... 
dev~fish-and-lily> y = Y(id="abc")
dev~fish-and-lily> y.put()
Key('X', 'abc')
dev~fish-and-lily> z = Z(id="abc")
dev~fish-and-lily> z.put()
Key('X', 'abc')
dev~fish-and-lily> y.key.get()
Z(key=Key('X', 'abc'), class_=[u'X', u'Z'])

dev~fish-and-lily> z.key.get()
Z(key=Key('X', 'abc'), class_=[u'X', u'Z'])
```

This is the problem you ran into. By adding the provider type as part of the key you now get distinct keys.

```
dev~fish-and-lily> z = Z(id="Zabc")
dev~fish-and-lily> z.put()
Key('X', 'Zabc')
dev~fish-and-lily> y = Y(id="Yabc")
dev~fish-and-lily> y.put()
Key('X', 'Yabc')
dev~fish-and-lily> y.key.get()
Y(key=Key('X', 'Yabc'), class_=[u'X', u'Y'])
dev~fish-and-lily> z.key.get()
Z(key=Key('X', 'Zabc'), class_=[u'X', u'Z'])
dev~fish-and-lily>
```

I don't believe this is any less convenient a model for you.

Does all that make sense ;-)

Comment: Thats a very interesting solution. I am still trying to understand your solution in full. So you have a `facebook_login` model that references the `User` model.  `facebook_login` has the `facebook_user_id` as the key, so a get() is really fast. And then you have the user reference and can do another get() to get the actual `User` object. This works because `User` model is using the reference key as the actual key.  Have I understood you correctly? and you could have another `twitter_login` for further providers etc..

Comment: Yep thats exactly it.  You can store any other auth type specific details in this entity, without cluttering up the user object.  I would probably use a PolyModel base class, so you can inherit basic properties and create login type specific classes.

Comment: Thanks for the update Tim. It is a good tip regarding how to get all the provider classes via filter if ever needed.  But in essence once I have got the facebookLogin instance via its fb_id key, all I need to do to get the actual user object would be `facebookLogin.user`, correct?

Comment: Yes.  I mentioned the polymodel query as I assume the user would need to manage their login identities.

Comment: after further analysis, I decided to pick your solution. But came across a problem. May you please be so kind and check the updated question please?

Comment: Ok, your problem is missing how PolyModels work.  All base classes of a base PolyModel share the same kind.  In your case AuthLogin so to fetch an entity you will by constructing the key using AuthLogin kind  or SubClass.get_by_id(someid)  so to ensure you don't have id clashes between login types you will need to concatenate the id with the auth type as per the other suggestions.  In my answer I did mention still creating the key from the provider type and id - though re-reading may be not clearly enough.

Comment: +1 thanks. It worked great!  The great thing is we can now combine several facebook accounts as well with this approach.

Comment: a followup question, remember `providers = AuthProvider.query().filter(AuthProvider.user_key == user.key)` ? Now when I loop through my providers, is there a way to see what the subtype of that provider is? (e.g. facebookLogin or GoogleLogin?) Or is the lookup of the first two characters of the id (e.. fb or gg) the only reliable way? Thanks

Comment: Unless you store more detail about the provider in AuthProvider then the prefix you have in the key is all you have to work with.

Answer (score 2):

While @Greg's answer seems OK, I think it's actually a bad idea to associate an external type/id as a key for your entity, because this solution doesn't scale very well.

- What if you would like to implement your own username/password at one point?
- What if the user going to delete their Facebook account?
- What if the same user wants to sign in with a Twitter account as well?
- What if the user has more than one Facebook accounts?

So the idea of having the type/id as key looks weak. A better solution would be to have a field for every type to store only the id. For example `facebook_id`, `twitter_id`, `google_id` etc, then query on these fields to retrieve the actual user. This will happen during sign-in and signup process so it's not that often. Of course you will have to add some logic to add another provider for an already existed user or merge users if the same user signed in with a different provider.

Still the last solution won't work if you want to support multiple sign-ins from the same provider. In order to achieve that you will have to create another model that will store only the external providers/ids and associate them with your user model.

As an example of the second solution you could check my [gae-init](https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init) project where I'm storing the 3 different providers in the [User](https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init/src/tip/main/model.py) model and working on them in the [auth.py](https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init/src/tip/main/auth.py) module. Again this solution doesn't not scale very well with more providers and doesn't support multiple IDs from the same provider.

Comment: Interesting solution. However let say I signin first with twitter and then I sign in with facebook https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init/src/tip/main/auth.py#cl-300. I would still get two different accounts. 1) The merge doesn't happen, does it? Unless we drive this separately though the settings page, where user can login through several providers to merge them to one account. 2) Couldn't you improve the query performance by indexing `facebook_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, default='')` though? 3) If the users grow, how much slower is this solution compared to concatenated key?

Comment: @Kave 1. there is no logic on realizing if that's the same user and there is no merge implemented, because it really depends on the app so I'm leaving that to the user.. 2. you're right.. they should be indexed.. 3. Not sure exactly but it shouldn't be affected by the size of the User model

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating the user-type with their ID is sensible.

You can save on your read and write costs by not duplicating the type and ID as properties though - when you need to use them, just split the ID back up. (Doing this will be simpler if you include a separator between the parts, `'%s|%s' % (provider_type, provider_id)` for example)

Comment: while I agree with the concatenation I don't agree with not saving the type and id separately.. cause you might want to filter for example to only facebook or twitter users..! Storage is cheap after all..

Comment: @Lipis very interesting blog. Gave me something to think about. I do it still the old way. Its hard to go against what a lifetime you have preached to. :) So now we denormalize data again. I didn't understand your comment regarding not separating id and type.  As you can see from my model,they both are separate and allow filtering on them, right? But the key has to be concatenated, otherwise it could be that both facebook and twitter have the same numerical id for the user. By concatenating `fb` or `tw` to teh end, we make sure that doesn't happen. Unless we can set two indexes on both fields?

Comment: In this answer Greg is recommending not duplicating the type and ID, which means to not store them in the Datastore.. while I believe that is better (as you are doing it) to store them.. to speed up the read and not having to split or whatever else is needed to extract this data.. and yes the key has to be concatenated..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a single model, you can do something like:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    providers = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

auser = User(id="auser", name="A user", email="auser@example.com")
auser.providers = [
    ndb.Key("ProviderName", "fb", "ProviderId", 123),
    ndb.Key("ProviderName", "tw", "ProviderId", 123)
]
auser.put()
```

To query for a specific FB login, you simple do:

```
fbkey = ndb.Key("ProviderName", "fb", "ProviderId", 123)
for entry in User.query(User.providers==fbkey):
    # Do something with the entry
```

As `ndb` does not provide an easy way to create a unique constraint, you could use the [_pre_put_hook](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__pre_put_hook) to ensure that `providers` is unique.

Comment: Thanks Marcos, @TimHoffman doesn't need the concat key, since in your facebook_authorized() method (the callback) you know you could only be here if the callback came from facebook in first place. Hence you would lookup `FacebookLogin` and not `TwitterLogin` in the method. Hence it doesn't matter if there would be a repeated key for both providers, because you know the type already.