# GAE implementing consistant facebook login using Datastore

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am implementing an mobile app for android and iOS and I am using GAE with the datastore for persistance as the server side of my app. My app uses facebook login for user authentication. One of the key aspects of the app is that users can interact with each other through the app but I want to keep their actual facebook-id secret so that user cannot discover the facebook profile of another user through my app.

My original design for this was using MySQL and there I had a simple implementation of a users table with the table primary key, an auto-increment integer served as the user id for the app. So I could safely send the user id of other users to the client app, and this did not give away any information I did not want to give away. When a user logs in, the client app performs all the necessary facebook login procedures and sends the facebook access token to the server. The server would extract the facebook user information from this token chech if a user with this id already exists, if so use this user row, otherwise create a new one.

On an SQL database this works great since it is strongly consistent, and there is no way I will "miss" the fact that the user is already in the table. However now when I am using the eventual consistent datastore with the same idea, I ran into a problem where if a user logs in for the first time ever, an entry is added to the datastore, but then if the user logs in again shortly after the query I am performing to check if a "User" entity with the same facebook-id is already present this query sometimes still return no results. This leads to the same facebook id being assosiated with 2 different users of my app and this is obviously bad.

(I know this seems like an unlikely scenario, but I actually accidentally ran into it during development)

I thought of a few ways to mitigate this:

1. Instead of using the app user id as the entity key use the facebook id, this ensures consistency (since there is no index involved in the lookup now). This would imply I need to use the facebook id as the id for my app and this violates one of the design principles (the facebook id of other users will now leak to the client app).
2. Instead of relying on the datastore generated entity key id for the user, specify the id myself, by performing some sort of deterministic manipulation of the facebook user id, such as a hashing it or encrypting it. This way I can use the key to perform the lookup and no matter how many times the same user logs in their user id will be generated the same. But this seems like too heavy an approach to do correctly. If I hash it I will need to make sure to use a good hashing algorithm to prevent collisions. A good hash or encryption will output a long string as a user id, which is not too bad, but I would like to keep the user id as a simple long integer value if possible.
3. Accept the fact that this is eventually consistent, during a log in if we find more then one corresponding entity, delete them and stay with one. This is bad, because what if the user has already performed some operations that are stored on the previous entity? I will have to run through all the data for the multiple user entities from the same user and perform some sort of merging operation on them. This will also require me to run through other entities that store the user id and change them all.
4. Use memcache to store the user, this will probably make this scenario even more unlikely, but not eliminate it entirely. Memcache entries can be evicted prematurely, and in this case we are back to swaure one.

What is the best approach here? Is there something I am missing? Would really appropriate your input.

Comment: Don't perform a query, get the user record by id this is always consistent . Have a look at this discussion  for one approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433607/is-it-possible-to-set-two-fields-as-indexes-on-an-entity-in-ndb/17438136#17438136

Comment: Definitely use @TimHoffman's solution posted to that question.